# File is not getting deleted?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

This line is showing true but  still not getting deleted from storage

```
fun delete(file: File  ,context: Context , pagesNO : List<Int> ,name : String ) {


    val d0 = file.delete()


    Log.i(TAG, "is deleted ${d0}")
    //    return
}
```

I want to delete the file to external storage.

Comment: Does it return true or false? Did you ask for permissions for accessing external storage?

Comment: Which file are you talking about?

Comment: Yeah its returning true and permission is granted

Comment: hi thanksthe issue is resolved actually the uri was changed ?
@m0skit0